# Automatic resizing of controls in javafx2

Tags: java, javafx-2

I am trying to add a ToolBar control, containing 2 Buttons and a TextField in my scene graph. 
I want that the TextField control gets automatically resized and acquire all the space available into toolbar. So, I used the HBox layout control to add the buttons and textfield.
I did as followed:

```
ToolBar tb = new ToolBar();
    HBox hbox = new HBox(8);
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    HBox.setHgrow(tf, Priority.ALWAYS);
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Button("<-"));
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Button("->"));
    hbox.getChildren().add(tf);            
    tb.getItems().add(hbox);
```

But its not working. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next:

```
    ToolBar tb = new ToolBar();
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    HBox hbox = new HBox(8);
    hbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(tb.widthProperty().subtract(20));
    HBox.setHgrow(tf, Priority.ALWAYS);
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Button("<-"));
    hbox.getChildren().add(new Button("->"));
    hbox.getChildren().add(tf);
    tb.getItems().add(hbox);
```